# jQuery Photo Viewer w/ Prev and Next Buttons

Tags: jquery, slideshow, photo-gallery

I am trying to code a Photo Viewer with Previous and Next Navigation Options in jQuery. It is completely functional with the exception of the Previous Navigation Button. I am quite perplexed because the "prevoius" button actually works if the "Next" button is pushed first, but if the "Previous" button is pressed first, not only does nothing happen, but the "Next" button breaks as well! Ideas??? I'm thinking it's probably an initialization problem...

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("a:has(img.gallery_photo)").click(function(event) {
    var showPath = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    var curPhoto = this;
    var nextPhoto = $(this).next();

    if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
        nextPhoto = $("#gallery a:first");
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    // Previous Button
    $("#photo_show a#back").click(function(event) {
        var placeHolder2 = curPhoto;
        event.preventDefault();
        nextPhoto = curPhoto;
        curPhoto = placeHolder2.prev(); 
        if(curPhoto.length == 0){
            curPhoto = $("#gallery a:last");
        }
        $("span#display_photo").html("<img src=\"" + curPhoto.attr("href") + "\" width=\"500\" height=\"350\"/>");
        $("p#caption").html("<p id=\"caption\"><em>" + curPhoto.attr("title") + "</em> </p>");
    });

    // Next Button
    $("#photo_show a#next").click(function(event) {
    var placeHolder = nextPhoto;
        event.preventDefault();
        curPhoto = nextPhoto;
        nextPhoto = placeHolder.next();
        if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
            nextPhoto = $("#gallery a:first");
        }           
        $("span#display_photo").html("<img src=\"" + curPhoto.attr("href") + "\" width=\"500\" height=\"350\"/>");
        $("p#caption").html("<p id=\"caption\"><em>" + curPhoto.attr("title") + "</em></p>");
    });

    $("span#display_photo").html("<img src=\"" + showPath + "\" width=\"500\" height=\"350\"/>");
    $("p#caption").html("<p id=\"caption\"><em>" + caption + "</em></p>");
    $("#photo_show").fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>  
<div id="photo_show">
    <table id="photo_nav">
        <tr>
            <td width="10%" align="left"><a id="back" href=""><img src="prev.png" alt="Click for Previous Photo"/></a></td>
            <td width="80%" align="center"><span id="display_photo"><img src="Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg" width="500" height="350"/></span></td>
            <td width="10%" align="right"><a id="next" href=""><img src="next.png" alt="Click for Next Photo"/></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>  
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg" title="Desert"><img class="gallery_photo" src="Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg" width="200" height="130" alt="Cannot Be Displayed"/></a>
    <a href="Sample Pictures/Jellyfish.jpg" title="Jellyfish"><img class="gallery_photo" src="Sample Pictures/Jellyfish.jpg" width="200" height="130" alt="Cannot Be Displayed"/></a>
    <a href="Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg" title="Koala"><img class="gallery_photo" src="Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg" width="200" height="130" alt="Cannot Be Displayed"/></a>
</div>      
</body>
```